# Trying to code a method to sort through a 5-card poker hand and evaluate if the hand has a single-pair, exclusively in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, methods, do-while

The method seems to work well at evaluating if there is the presence of a single-pair in the hand or not. However, I'm trying to figure out how to code in if another hand comes up as true (two pair, 4 of a kind, full house, etc) that the pair should return as false. Here's the code I have for the ruling IN of a pair while ruling out everything else. I essentially went hand-by-hand with the potential combinations of a potential pair and utilized the '^' operator to create the exclusivity.

```
    // if-else statements to rule in a pair exclusively
    if ((cards[0] == cards[1]) ^ (cards[0] == cards[2]) ^ (cards[0] == cards[3]) ^ (cards[0] == cards[4])){
        isPair = true;
    } else if ((cards[1] == cards[2]) ^ (cards[1] == cards[3]) ^ (cards[1] == cards[4])){
        isPair =true;
    } else if ((cards[2] == cards[3]) ^ (cards[2] == cards[4])){
        isPair = true;
    } else if (cards[3] == cards[4]){
        isPair = true;
    } else 
        isPair = false;
    return isPair;
```

I had thought with the use of '^' that it would have made it that so if it had found another pair within it, but it is still coming up as "true" when running hands that have a two pair. I tried adding another int variable tooManyPairs and incremented inside of the if-else statements every time it found a pair while in do-while loop. Here's what it looked like:

```
    public boolean isPair(){
    boolean isPair = false;
    int tooManyPairs = 0;
    int [] cards = new int [hand.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++){
        cards[i] = hand[i].getRank();
    }
    // if-else loops to rule out 4 of a kind
    do {
    // if-else statements to rule in a pair exclusively
    if ((cards[0] == cards[1]) ^ (cards[0] == cards[2]) ^ (cards[0] == cards[3]) ^ (cards[0] == cards[4])){
        isPair = true;
        tooManyPairs++;
    } else if ((cards[1] == cards[2]) ^ (cards[1] == cards[3]) ^ (cards[1] == cards[4])){
        isPair =true;
        tooManyPairs++;
    } else if ((cards[2] == cards[3]) ^ (cards[2] == cards[4])){
        isPair = true;
        tooManyPairs++;
    } else if (cards[3] == cards[4]){
        isPair = true;
        tooManyPairs++;
    } else 
        isPair = false;
    }while (tooManyPairs < 1);
    if (tooManyPairs > 1)
        return isPair = false;
    return isPair;
```

The [image]

The output is still coming up as true for both instead of just the two pair. I thought I could repost the previous code for those methods into this method with modifications that would make them return the isPair method as false. That just seems like a lot of excess code and I feel like there should be a more simple way of doing it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Using XOR is a mistake. Try debugging some hand variations and you'll see why.

Comment: @Bohemian I'm not sure what you mean with that.

Comment: `^` is a logical XOR operation. Both `true ^ false ^ true` and `false ^ false ^ false` evaluate to `false`. Depending on the order or comparisons, finding multiple pairs in your chain of XORs may evaluate as if none were found. I think you want a logical OR - try changing `^` to `||`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because this is homework, I'll give pseudo code only...

I think you're going about it the hard way. Try this:

- collect the rank of cards in the hand into an array of ranks
- sort the array of ranks
- iterate over the array (once) and count the number of times adjacent ranks are the same
- return true if the count is 1, false otherwise

Consider that using this approach will calculate 3 of a kind as 2 pairs when it's actually *3* pairs (and 4 of a kind *6* pairs), but that won't affect correctness of this approach.

Comment: ughhhhh so much easier lmao thank you very much. It's working right now. Gonna keep trying to break it. Might have to go back through the other methods and try and simplify them just to get better at this.